# display data on chart.s

Tags: javascript, angular, charts, chart.js

i am using angular and i required to draw a graph/chart i have a data that contains name and time.

in the above situtaion name represents the name of customer and the time represent tha time of call he make(a single customer can make several calls  so a customer can have many times). i want to draw a chart in such a way that we can see a customer make a call on this time.

i tried to use chart.js and try line and scatter chart but unable to get desired result.
any suggestion which chart i can use and or how to achieve this

thankyou in advance

Comment: Try using a bar chart. With the customers on the X axes and the time it took on the y axes. Will give the best result

Comment: @LeeLenalee sir i already tried this but it didnt work in my case

Answer (score 0):

Using a [scatter chart](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/scatter.html) is a good choice. The solution however depends on the format of your data. Let's presume, it looks like this:

```
const data = [
  { name: 'Rachel', calls: ['2021-03-01 10:15', '2021-03-01 18:02', '2021-03-02 06:48'] },
  { name: 'William', calls: ['2021-03-01 13:24', '2021-03-02 08:41', '2021-03-02 11:13'] },
  { name: 'Barbara', calls: ['2021-03-01 07:58', '2021-03-01 15:47', '2021-03-02 10:16'] }
];
```

You need to create a `dataset` for each user and provide the data in [point format](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/scatter.html#data-structure) where the values of distinct users are different but all values of a same user are identical. This can be done using the [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method as follows:

```
data.map((user, i) => ({ 
  label: user.name,
  data: user.calls.map(call => ({ x: call, y: i + 1 }))
}))
```

Now you also need to define a [`ticks.callback`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/labelling.html#creating-custom-tick-formats) function on the y-axis that transforms the numeric tick value back to the user name

```
yAxes: [{
  ticks: {
    ...
    callback: v => v % 1 == 0 ? data[v - 1].name : undefined
  }
}],
```

Please take a look at below runnable code and see how it works.

```js
const data = [
  { name: 'Rachel', calls: ['2021-03-01 10:15', '2021-03-01 18:02', '2021-03-02 06:48'] },
  { name: 'William', calls: ['2021-03-01 13:24', '2021-03-02 08:41', '2021-03-02 11:13'] },
  { name: 'Barbara', calls: ['2021-03-01 07:58', '2021-03-01 15:47', '2021-03-02 10:16'] }
];
const colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green'];

new Chart('myChart', {
  type: 'scatter',
  data: {
    datasets: data.map((user, i) => ({ 
      label: user.name,
      data: user.calls.map(call => ({ x: call, y: i + 1 })),
      backgroundColor: colors[i],
      pointRadius: 4
    }))
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    tooltips: {
      callbacks: {
        title: tooltipItem => data[tooltipItem[0].datasetIndex].name,
        label: tooltipItem => tooltipItem.xLabel
      }
    },
    scales: {   
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          min: 0.5,
          max: data.length + 0.5,
          stepSize: 0.5,
          callback: v => v % 1 == 0 ? data[v - 1].name : undefined
        }
      }],
      xAxes: [{
        type: 'time',
        time: {
          unit: 'hour',
          displayFormats: {
            hour: 'MMM-DD HH'
          },
          tooltipFormat: 'MMM-DD HH:mm'
        },
        gridLines: {
          lineWidth: 0
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="80"></canvas>
```